# English with Harry Potter

Tags: learning

I'm just reading Harry Potter, though people say reading books is not going to improve my speaking fluency.

I'm just reading it, marking down all the text I feel I would not be able to say myself, and then learning.

I've made three different diaries for idioms, word meanings, and Harry Potter text.

Is it a good idea, will this ever result in improving my English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it definitely can improve your English; however, *Harry Potter* is a tough book to read, so I'd start out small if I were you.  There are very tough idioms and strange grammatical structures in *Harry Potter*.  J.K. Rowling has a penchant for archaisms and odd constructions.  I have read some of her *Harry Potter* books and I can recall her using oddities such as "span" as the past tense of "spin" when it's the archaic simple past tense; "spun" is the modern simple past tense.  I just think it's not the best book to start with; however, if you like *Harry Potter* that much, then you're doing a great job of making three different diaries for idioms, word meanings, and *Harry Potter* text.  This will definitely improve your language skills and help you eventually master the language. I commend you for it, so don't listen to people who have tried to discourage you. Reading books will definitely improve your speaking skills *in time*. I guarantee it!  Godspeed and good luck in your endeavors.

Comment: Nick, do you have any advice on a good book to read?